# ranorex: Who is using my floating license?

Tags: ranorex

If I have a floating license for Ranorex 5.4, and I have several machines running. Can I tell which machine is using the license from the license server? If so, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- On the licence server, start the **Ranorex License Manager** (use the
  start menu).
- Select the licence in the table shown, then click on
  **Clients** tab at the bottom.

The **host** and the **user** using the license will be shown.